Stop typed moves above or below some letters
When typing a stop (.) immediately after letters d h l m n r s t moves the stop automatically below the letters  It appears as ḍ ḥ ḷ ṃ ṇ ṛ ṣ ṭ  Ḍ Ḥ Ḷ Ṃ Ṇ Ṛ Ṣ Ṭ even on  this post !!!   My language settings are English (United States). I also have Sanskrit.
When typing a stop before m  n  the stop moves above   as in ṁ  ṅ  Ṁ Ṅ

I have been using these languages for a long time.
I have not made any changes
I have not noticed other diacritics
I suspect my pressing some keys inadvertently has caused this?


What you describe is actually what would happen in sanskrit, so it looks like you've switched to that keyboard layout. Try pressing CTRL-SHIFT or ALT-SHIFT (hold first, press second) and see if the problem goes away.

@Ramhound not true. Dual keyboard layouts have been part of windows since Windows 95, maybe even 3.11.

@LPChip - It absolutely is clear that Windows 7 Ultimate was the only version that allowed you to install multiple language packs, but dual-layout keyboards do not disqualify that fact. Windows 8 was the first version that allowed Home and Professional (mainly because there wasn’t an Ultimate) the user to install multiple language packs. Windows Vista was the first version to allow the user to install either 32-bit or 64-bit.

I am using Windows7 Ultimate only,  While I had used switching languages by keys, I use the Language Bar, I have now docked the Language bar  in my Task Baṛ  and can always see iṭ .  You can see the "under-dots" in this message itself.  The language did not switcḥ.

I'm still very sure that it is one of the installed keyboard languages you have. If you don't have United States keyboard layout installed, add it, and switch to it. If what I'm saying is correct, the problem would then disappear. You can also add United States Internatonal to add the function "e to generate ë.

As mentioned in comments, it is because you have Sanskrit installed as well.
You can switch between the installed languages (for keyboard) using a shortcut. On my machine it has defaulted to Left alt+shift.
When it happens inadvertently, just press the key sequence to go to the next keyboard language.
You can get to setup screen

Task bar
Click on language icon, on mine it says ENG
Select Language Preferences
Click on Keyboard
Click on Input language hot keys

There you can change the key sequence

